# Android layer-list spritesheet

Tags: android, list, sprite, layer

I have created a sprite sheet (single image that contains multiple images) with 4 different icons. I would like to create a layer-list that uses different parts of the images to make a single image, for example:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spritesheet"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spritesheet"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spritesheet"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spritesheet"/>
</layer-list>
```

For example the sprite sheet would look something like this:

[image: Sprite Sheet]

and I would like the final result to look like this:

[image]

I have tried the different options that are available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) 
 however I can't find a solution.

Comment: In your example you are using the same drawable , is it just as an example ?

Comment: I want to be able to use the same drawable but different parts of it, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the parts of the picture?

@drawable/layers.xml, for example:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/part1"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/part2"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/part3"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/part4"/>
</layer-list>
```

And if the full picture is needed, you can use a fifth (the full) picture, or create it from the parts  in a RelativeLayout thus it remains the app light-weight.